# App not able to extract json data

Tags: android, json

I am trying to extract Json data, but somehow the code is not working.
 Can somebody please help me ? Can't seem to understand what i am doing wrong.

(I dont really hav any more details to add)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.exchangeRate);
        Anindya task = new Anindya();
        task.execute("xyz");
    }
    public class Anindya extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                int data = reader.read();

                while (data!= 0)
                {
                    char current = (char)data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i("website content",result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting? What are you expecting? Please read on creating a minimal, verifiable, complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am expecting to extract the JSON data and displaying in the logcat

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in)` with `InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in)`

If it still doesn't solve your problem then try to check the value of `data` and post details about returned value.

Comment: Try changing **data != -1** .I am sorry for using the word "try", as I don't have enough knowledge about HTTP-request, I work with Volley (it really works better than http)